# Navigation bar goes to top of screen after being pushed from another view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers, "Facility" and "Details View Controller" both of which are have Table Views. Facility stems from a Navigation based controller in my storyboard but the Details View Controller doesn't because it is instantiated when one of the cells in Facility is clicked. The problem is that DetailsViewController's doesn't have a navigation bar like the others. It is at the top of the screen. I have tried following different answers and doing research (embedding a navigation view didn't work) but nothing seems to work.

I will demonstrate my issue with screenshots to better illustrate the problem: 
[image: Facility (comes from Navigation Controller in storyboard)]

Details View Controller: [image: Details View Controller (not connected to navigation controller in storyboard]

This is what both views look like when they are run:
[image: Facility View]

[image: Details View Controller]

As you can see, the Details View Controller is instantiated when one of the cells in Facility is clicked, but the navigation bar goes to the top. It is not connected to the navigation controller in storyboard because, like I said, it should only be instantiated when a cell is clicked.

This is the code I have for clicking a cell in Facility:

```
//when a user selects a row (i.e. cell)
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
 {

    if nil == self.detailsViewController
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.detailsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
    }

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.detailsViewController, animated:true)
}
```

Please help me figure out how to fix the navigation problem in DetailsViewController.

Comment: Why don't you just segue to the detailsViewController? A segue will also instantiate the view controller, and it will avoid the awkward `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: How would I segue from the storyborad if detailsViewController is only supposed to appear when one of the cells are clicked?

Comment: Add UINavigationbar to your detailsViewController from storyboard and then try.

Comment: One specific cell or any cell? You can control-drag from the table view cell if any cell should trigger the segue, or you can control-drag from the yellow circle with the white square in the view hierarchy that says Facility next to it. Name the segue, then in code check which cell was tapped then say `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier")` if appropriate.